# Unable to establish connection in Flask-socketio with namepaces[routes]

Tags: python, flask, websocket, flask-socketio

I am trying to emit a event on route/namespace "/chat" but I keep on getting error `/chat is not a connected namespace`.

Here is my server side code:

```py
from config import socket
from flask_socketio import send, emit
from flask import Blueprint

admin_sockets = Blueprint('admin_sockets', __name__)


@socket.on('connect')
def test_connect(auth):
    emit('my response', {'data': 'Connected'})


@socket.on('getcase',  namespace='/chat')
def handleMessage(msg):
    print('YOOOOHOOOO: ' + str(msg))
    send(msg, broadcast=True)
    # def tryy():
    #     '''rwre'''


@socket.on('message')
def handleMessage(msg):
    print('Message: ' + str(msg))
    send(msg, broadcast=True)
```

And here is the client-side code:

```py
import socketio

# standard Python
sio = socketio.Client()


@sio.event
def connect():
    print("I'm connected!")
    sio.emit(
        'message', {'userKey': 'Your Streaming API Key'})


@sio.event
def connect_error():
    print("The connection failed!")


@sio.on('handshake')
def on_message(data):
    print('HandShake', data)
    # sio.emit('message', {'symbol': 'EURUSD'})


@sio.on('message')
def on_message(data):
    print('Price Data ', data)
    sio.emit('getcase', {'userKey': '2'}, namespace='/chat')
```

But when I run the code I get exception as

```
I'm connected!
Price Data  {'userKey': 'Your Streaming API Key'}
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jayendra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\jayendra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jayendra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\socketio\client.py", line 705, in _handle_eio_message
    self._handle_event(pkt.namespace, pkt.id, pkt.data)
  File "C:\Users\jayendra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\socketio\client.py", line 581, in _handle_event
    r = self._trigger_event(data[0], namespace, *data[1:])
  File "C:\Users\jayendra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\socketio\client.py", line 629, in _trigger_event
    return self.handlers[namespace][event](*args)
  File "C:\tai_jutsu\hackathon_v3\sih-backend\websocket_client.py", line 35, in on_message
    sio.emit('getcase', {'userKey': '2'}, namespace='/chat')
  File "C:\Users\jayendra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\socketio\client.py", line 393, in emit
    raise exceptions.BadNamespaceError(
socketio.exceptions.BadNamespaceError: /chat is not a connected namespace.
```

Can anyone please tell me where is the bug, thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't included the connection call from the client. That is where you specify which namespaces you want to connect on.

Comment: `sio.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000',
            headers=head, namespaces=['/chat', '/'])`